# How to call original function after it's been overridden in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, overriding

I serialize most of my classes with two functions, read() and write(). What I would like to do is have the read/write() function of the base class called from the subclasses so that I don't have to repeat the serialization code multiple times.

For example:

```
class Base
{
public:
   base();
   virtual read(QDataStream&);
   virtual write(QDataStream&);
private:
   int a, b, c, d;
}

class Sub : public Base
{
public:
    Sub();
    read(QDataStream&);
    write(QDataStream&);
private:
    int e, f, g, h;
}
```

So in this example, i would like the code to read/write a,b,c,d to come from Base. Sub would then call Base::read(QDataStream&) and then add whatever attributes are unique to Sub. This way I don't have to repeat the serialization code for each subclass (and possibly forget to do so).

Comment: Note that this is actually called "overriding" a method. "Overloading" is when you have several methods that have the same name but which take different types of arguments. For example, a string class might overload operator+() to give the + operator meaning when strings are involved.

Comment: You should try to make the examples correct. The member functions are missing the return types, the type is called `Base`, but there seems to be a `base` constructor...

Comment: thanks for the clarication Caleb.

Comment: Is there a way to do this outside OOP.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can call base-class functions by prepending the function call with the base-class identifier, followed by the scope operator (::).

Like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
     virtual void Function();
}

class Foo : public Base
{
public:
     void Function();
     void DoSomething();
}

void Foo::DoSomething()
{
     Base::Function();   // Will call the base class' version of Function().
     Function();         // Will call Foo's version of Function().
}
```

EDIT: Note removed by request.

Comment: Please, remove the whole *added note*, it is completely off-topic, and worse: incorrect. The initializer list and the qualified member function calls are completely unrelated. They don't even have the same syntax, the only thing in common is that the name of the base type appears somewhere in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation

Comment: @David: I would like to point out that the code in the note would compile and does what I explained it would do. I did remove it however, since I agree it was offtopic (as I mentioned in the answer). I was under the assumption that there was no harm in attempting to provide additional information that was related (albeit not completely), if I clearly mentioned the point in the post where the exact answer ended and the additional information started (as was the case).

Answer (score 10):

```
void Sub::read(QDataStream &stream)
{
    Base::read(stream);
    // do Sub stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First off - your member functions don't have return types - not valid in C++, your compiler might complain about 'default int' behavior and let it pass, but you should give them return types (I'll use `void` as a placeholder).

You can scope resolve and use the parent class version when you're in a subclass:

```
void Sub::read(QDataStream& qds) {
    Base::read(qds);

    // do more stuff
}
```